# MersenneTwister - Same pseudo random number in Android(java) and C (Arduino)

Tags: android, random, arduino, prng, mersenne-twister

I have to use one pseudo random number generator to get the same number with the same seed in different platforms.

I tried to set the "seed" in random class in Android(java) and Arduino(c), and they give me different numbers with the same seed, and what I need is the SAME number with the SAME seed in both systems.

So, I tried "Mersenne Twister" to get the same pseudo random number in both systems.

This is my code in Arduino Library:

```
/* 
   A C-program for MT19937, with initialization improved 2002/1/26.
   Coded by Takuji Nishimura and Makoto Matsumoto.

   Before using, initialize the state by using init_genrand(seed)  
   or init_by_array(init_key, key_length).

   Copyright (C) 1997 - 2002, Makoto Matsumoto and Takuji Nishimura,
   All rights reserved.                          

   Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
   modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
   are met:

     1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
        notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.

     2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
        notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
        documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.

     3. The names of its contributors may not be used to endorse or promote 
        products derived from this software without specific prior written 
        permission.

   THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
   "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
   LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
   A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
   CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
   EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
   PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
   PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
   LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
   NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
   SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.


   Any feedback is very welcome.
   http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html
   email: m-mat @ math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp (remove space)
*/

//#include <stdio.h>

/* Period parameters */  
#define N 624
#define M 397
#define MATRIX_A 0x9908b0dfUL   /* constant vector a */
#define UPPER_MASK 0x80000000UL /* most significant w-r bits */
#define LOWER_MASK 0x7fffffffUL /* least significant r bits */

static unsigned int mt[N]; /* the array for the state vector  */
static int mti=N+1; /* mti==N+1 means mt[N] is not initialized */

/* initializes mt[N] with a seed */
void init_genrand(unsigned long s)
{
    mt[0]= s & 0xffffffffUL;
    for (mti=1; mti<N; mti++) {
        mt[mti] = 
        (1812433253UL * (mt[mti-1] ^ (mt[mti-1] >> 30)) + mti); 
        /* See Knuth TAOCP Vol2. 3rd Ed. P.106 for multiplier. */
        /* In the previous versions, MSBs of the seed affect   */
        /* only MSBs of the array mt[].                        */
        /* 2002/01/09 modified by Makoto Matsumoto             */
        mt[mti] &= 0xffffffffUL;
        /* for >32 bit machines */
    }
}

/* initialize by an array with array-length */
/* init_key is the array for initializing keys */
/* key_length is its length */
/* slight change for C++, 2004/2/26 */
void init_by_array(unsigned long init_key[], int key_length)
{
    int i, j, k;
    init_genrand(19650218UL);
    i=1; j=0;
    k = (N>key_length ? N : key_length);
    for (; k; k--) {
        mt[i] = (mt[i] ^ ((mt[i-1] ^ (mt[i-1] >> 30)) * 1664525UL))
          + init_key[j] + j; /* non linear */
        mt[i] &= 0xffffffffUL; /* for WORDSIZE > 32 machines */
        i++; j++;
        if (i>=N) { mt[0] = mt[N-1]; i=1; }
        if (j>=key_length) j=0;
    }
    for (k=N-1; k; k--) {
        mt[i] = (mt[i] ^ ((mt[i-1] ^ (mt[i-1] >> 30)) * 1566083941UL))
          - i; /* non linear */
        mt[i] &= 0xffffffffUL; /* for WORDSIZE > 32 machines */
        i++;
        if (i>=N) { mt[0] = mt[N-1]; i=1; }
    }

    mt[0] = 0x80000000UL; /* MSB is 1; assuring non-zero initial array */ 
}

/* generates a random number on [0,0xffffffff]-interval */
unsigned long genrand_int32(void)
{
    unsigned long y;
    static unsigned long mag01[2]={0x0UL, MATRIX_A};
    /* mag01[x] = x * MATRIX_A  for x=0,1 */

    if (mti >= N) { /* generate N words at one time */
        int kk;

        if (mti == N+1)   /* if init_genrand() has not been called, */
            init_genrand(5489UL); /* a default initial seed is used */

        for (kk=0;kk<N-M;kk++) {
            y = (mt[kk]&UPPER_MASK)|(mt[kk+1]&LOWER_MASK);
            mt[kk] = mt[kk+M] ^ (y >> 1) ^ mag01[y & 0x1UL];
        }
        for (;kk<N-1;kk++) {
            y = (mt[kk]&UPPER_MASK)|(mt[kk+1]&LOWER_MASK);
            mt[kk] = mt[kk+(M-N)] ^ (y >> 1) ^ mag01[y & 0x1UL];
        }
        y = (mt[N-1]&UPPER_MASK)|(mt[0]&LOWER_MASK);
        mt[N-1] = mt[M-1] ^ (y >> 1) ^ mag01[y & 0x1UL];

        mti = 0;
    }

    y = mt[mti++];

    /* Tempering */
    y ^= (y >> 11);
    y ^= (y << 7) & 0x9d2c5680UL;
    y ^= (y << 15) & 0xefc60000UL;
    y ^= (y >> 18);

    return y;
}

/* generates a random number on [0,0x7fffffff]-interval */
long genrand_int31(void)
{
    return (long)(genrand_int32()>>1);
}

unsigned long generate_long(unsigned long n)
{
    unsigned long bits, val;
    do {
      bits = (genrand_int31() << 1);
      val = bits % n;
    } 
    while(bits - val + (n-1) < 0);
    return val;
}

/* generates a random number on [0,1]-real-interval */
double genrand_real1(void)
{
    return genrand_int32()*(1.0/4294967295.0); 
    /* divided by 2^32-1 */ 
}

/* generates a random number on [0,1)-real-interval */
double genrand_real2(void)
{
    return genrand_int32()*(1.0/4294967296.0); 
    /* divided by 2^32 */
}

/* generates a random number on (0,1)-real-interval */
double genrand_real3(void)
{
    return (((double)genrand_int32()) + 0.5)*(1.0/4294967296.0); 
    /* divided by 2^32 */
}

/* generates a random number on [0,1) with 53-bit resolution*/
double genrand_res53(void) 
{ 
    unsigned long a=genrand_int32()>>5, b=genrand_int32()>>6; 
    return(a*67108864.0+b)*(1.0/9007199254740992.0); 
} 
/* These real versions are due to Isaku Wada, 2002/01/09 added */
```

And this is my Mersenne Twister in java:
http://www.cs.gmu.edu/~sean/research/mersenne/MersenneTwister.java or http://www.cs.gmu.edu/~sean/research/mersenne/MersenneTwisterFast.java
The code in both .java is more or less equal, at least the result is the same.

May you help me why I cannot get the same pseudo random number?

Thanks in advance,
Best regards.

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! Could you take a look at ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question?

Comment: Java doesn't have unsigned numbers, so that eg it will **print** "-1" when  the generators returns 0xffffffff; I tried running those generators with a few random seed and they always print the same numbers, ie exactly the same if they are positive and equals (modulo 2^32) when java says negative. That being said, next time follow admdrew's advice!

Comment: I had this problem myself, made some adjustments so it doesn't generate negative numbers (because those are handled differently on the platforms) and also only generate 32 bit numbers so it works better with arduinos Print class. https://gist.github.com/narrowtux/4a1c94351d154544300b

Answer (score 1):

The original Mersenne Twister cannot run on MCU's with 2KB Ram.

Your change of mt[] from long to int break's it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [TinyMT](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/TINYMT/) if you want to stick with Mercenne Twister. Or you can even try [xoroshiro+ or XorShift+](http://xoroshiro.di.unimi.it/), which has much smaller code.